# I don't want Enter key trigger to submit

Tags: php, html

I have a form like

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```

When I press the Enter button I want it to do create a new line in text box (br) but Enter key triggers the submit and it submits the value instantly. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try the text area for input...<textarea name="test"></textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is probably the `<textarea>` element instead of `<input>`. The syntax is a little different, with the main difference being that there is no `type` attribute, and instead the "value" goes between the opening and closing tag:

```
<textarea name="test" rows="1">value here</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```

Note that `rows="1"` is simply to emulate `<text>`. If you want to allow newlines, you should probably use a higher value for that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try the text area for input

```
<textarea name="test"></textarea>
```